# $k[x,y]/(x^2-y, y-r) = k[x]/(x^2-r)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

> Show $R[x,y]/(x^2-y, y-r) = R[x]/(x^2-r)$

Intuitively it makes sense since the left hand side the quotient is just identifying $x^2$ as $y$ and $y$ as $r$.

To show this rigorously, I think I can use the isomorphism theorem
$$R[x,y]/(x^2-y, y-r) = \frac{R[x,y]/(y-r)}{(x^2-y, y-r)/(y-r)}$$
But then I know we can not replace things in the quotient with isomorphic things. For example $\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb Z} \neq \mathbb{Z}/{4\mathbb Z}$ where $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $4\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}-module$.

I this case, can I say the top $R[x,y]/(y-r)$ is in fact just $R[x]$? And I think the botton is not even isomorphic (as Abelian group) to $J$ since $\frac{I+J}{I} = \frac{J}{I\cap J}$.

**More generally, when can we replace things in a quotient by its isomorphic class.**

Comment: $2\mathbb Z$ and $4\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb Z$-modules, but they are not isomorphic as submodules! This is because submodule is not just an object, but it comes equipped with inclusion map (or more generally, appropriate monomorphism) and to be isomorphic as submodules, the isomorphism between $2\mathbb Z$ and $4\mathbb Z$ would have to respect the inclusions as well, but it is not the case. If you know about short exact sequences, it is precisely a case of 5 lemma that if the isomorphism of submodules commutes with inclusions, it induces isomorphism of quotient modules as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the remark, I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to turn my comment into a proper answer.

When you are thinking of subobjects and quotient objects, you always have to have in mind that these actually come equipped with morhpisms. Subobject $A$ of $X$ comes with inclusion map $A\hookrightarrow X$ (or more generally, monomorphism) and quotient object with epimorphism $X\twoheadrightarrow X/A$. These are organized nicely with [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence)

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>i>> X@>p>> X/A@>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

and exactness means that $i$ is monomorphism, $p$ is epimorphism and $\operatorname{im}i=\ker p.$

What you want to know is if $X\cong Y$ and $A\cong B$, when is $X/A\cong Y/B$. Luckily, this can easily be answered using short exact sequences.

Consider this situation:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>i_A>> X @>p_A>> X/A @>>> 0\\
&     @VVV    @VVfV  @VV?V \\
0 @>>> B @>i_B>> Y @>p_B>> Y/B @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

and the question is given morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ (not necessarily iso), when can we expect morphism $\bar f\colon X/A\to X/B$? Well, this is actually quite easy, we have $p_B\circ f\colon X\to Y/B$ and we know that we must have $A\subseteq\ker(p_B\circ f)$ which is the same thing as $f(A)\subseteq B$. So, we need to have well defined restriction $f|_A\colon A\to B$. This can be written as $f\circ i_A = i_B\circ f|_A$.

To summarize,

> **Lemma.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon A\to B$ such that $f\circ i_A = i_B\circ g$. Then there exists unique $h\colon X/A\to X/B$ such that $h\circ p_A = p_B \circ f$, i.e. there is following commutative diagram
>   $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> 0 @>>> A @>i_A>> X @>p_A>> X/A @>>> 0\\
> &     @VVgV    @VVfV  @VV\exists!\, hV \\
> 0 @>>> B @>i_B>> Y @>p_B>> Y/B @>>> 0
> \end{CD}$$

Written less mysteriously, $h([x]) =[f(x)]$, where $[\cdot]$ is appropriate equivalence class.

So, returning to the case of isomorphism $f\colon X\stackrel{\sim}\to Y$, we can have $X/A\cong Y/B$ only if $f(A) \subseteq B$. It turns out that $f(A) = B$ is enough, i.e.

> **Lemma.** (addendum) If $f$ and $g$ above are isomorphisms, then so is $h$.

You can use known tools such as first isomorphism theorem to prove it or directly from [five lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma).

As you can see, the problem with $2\mathbb Z$ and $4\mathbb Z$ is that even though they are isomorphic, there is no automorphism of $\mathbb Z$ (which is just $x\mapsto \pm x$) that restricts to it, and thus $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\not\cong\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z.$

Finally, let's see how to deal with your exercise using the tools we just mentioned. Write appropriate exact sequences:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \frac{(x^2-y,y-r)}{(y-r)} @>>> \frac{R[x,y]}{(y-r)} @>>> \frac{R[x,y]/(y-r)}{(x^2-y,y-r)/(y-r)} @>>> 0\\
&     @VVV    @VVV  @VVV \\
0 @>>> (x^2-r) @>>> R[x] @>>> R[x]/(x^2-r) @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

and note that isomorphism $R[x,y]/(y-r)\cong R[x]$ is given by evaluation map $$f(x,y) + (y-r)\mapsto f(x,r).$$ Now check that this evaluation map maps $(x^2-y,y-r)$ to $(x^2-r)$ and you are done.

Perhaps you've noticed that I haven't specified in which category is this isomorphism; take your pick: $\mathbb Z$-algebra, $R$-algebra or even $R[x]$-algebra - all you have to do is check that all the maps in the diagram are $R[x]$-linear and multiplicative (which all follows from evaluation map being such).

Answer (score 4):

There is a unique $R$-algebra homomorphism from $R[x,y]$ to $R[x]/(x^2-r)$
taking $x$ to $x$ and $y$ to $r$. Its kernel contains both $x^2-y$ and $y-r$ so induces an $R$-algebra homomorphism from $R[x,y]/(x^2-y,y-r)$
to $R[x]/(x^2-r)$.

Similar considerations show there is an $R$-algebra homomorphism in
the reverse direction taking $x$ to $x$. All we need to prove is that
these maps are inverse. This requires seeing where $x$ and $y$ get sent
to in their composites.