# $X\cong Y$ and $A\cong B$, when is $X/A\cong Y/B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

Suppose $X\cong Y$ and $A\cong B$. When is $X/A\cong Y/B$?

This is from one of my previous questions which was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375916/kx-y-x2-y-y-r-kx-x2-r).

The statement is true and it relies on the following lemma

> **Lemma.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon A\to B$ such that $f\circ i_A = i_B\circ g$. Then there exists unique $h\colon X/A\to X/B$ such that $h\circ p_A = p_B \circ f$, i.e. there is following commutative diagram
>   $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> 0 @>>> A @>i_A>> X @>p_A>> X/A @>>> 0\\
> &     @VVgV    @VVfV  @VV\exists!\, hV \\
> 0 @>>> B @>i_B>> Y @>p_B>> Y/B @>>> 0
> \end{CD}$$

The function $h$ is defined by $h([x]_{X/A}) = [f(x)]_{Y/B}$, can this be deduced from the 5-lemma or we need to do a diagram chase type of proof.

Comment: *What* statement is true?

Comment: Relevant information should not be title-only; it should always appear in the body of a question. I have edited your question to copy the information over.

Comment: It is certainly not true that if $X\cong Y$ and $A\cong B$, then $X/A\cong Y/B$!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see,  I have to be more precise for the isomorphisms. But is there any problem with the lemma?

Comment: @Xiao: $X=Y=A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B = 2\mathbb{Z}$. The critical premise that you're overlooking is that you need an isomorphism of diagrams, not just of the individual groups involved. In this case, a morphism from the diagram $A \xrightarrow{i_A} X$ and $B \xrightarrow{i_B} Y$ is a pair of group morphism $(g,f)$ that form a commutative square, as depicted in your picture, and it turns out to be invertible (i.e. an isomorphism) if both $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the commutativity of the left square, we can see that the map $p_B\circ f$ has kernel containing $A$, so factors uniquely through the quotient map $p_A:X\to X/A$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. So by the commutativity of the left square, we have $p_B\circ f\circ i_A = p_B\circ i_B\circ g = 0$, then follows from UMP.

Comment: To be precise, this is using the universal property of $X / A$ as the cokernel of $i_A$.